# Where is the definition of the ...Ptr naming standard

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is `robot_model::RobotModelPtr` or `robot_state::RobotStatePtr` defined? When searching through sources; I can see numerous usages of them; but I can't track down what they are and where they are defined.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361537/where-is-the-definition-of-the-...ptr-naming-standard/) by [bgraysea](https://answers.ros.org/users/56768/bgraysea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As discussed on the MoveIt Discord: They are just pointers to RobotModel and RobotState* (see [robot_model.h](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotModel.html) and [robot_state.h](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html) respectively). All the `xxxPtr`, `xxxConstPtr` etc. pointers are defined via `MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD` at the start of those header files. See [class_forward.h](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_core/html/class__forward_8h_source.html) and [declare_ptr.h](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_core/html/declare__ptr_8h_source.html) for the definition of that macro:

```
#define MOVEIT_DECLARE_PTR_MEMBER(Type)
typedef std::shared_ptr<Type> Ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<const Type> ConstPtr;
typedef std::weak_ptr<Type> WeakPtr;
typedef std::weak_ptr<const Type> ConstWeakPtr;
typedef std::unique_ptr<Type> UniquePtr;
typedef std::unique_ptr<const Type> ConstUniquePtr;
```

So not only RobotModelPtr, but also RobotModelConstPtr, RobotModelWeakPtr etc. are defined, but there is no explicit definition your IDE displays, and you won't find them with simple Ctrl+F.

I found this confusing as well, and it's not easy to figure out if you don't know the pattern. I'm not sure how to make it easier to discover when you read the code, but feel free to submit a PR with documentation.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-14**:
Any self-respecting IDE should be able to take you to these definitions after clicking on them. It should even be able to expand the macro for you.

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2020-09-15**:
Any self-respecting editor designed for writing code should be able to tab-complete `shared_ptr<>`.  Even vim does this for me.  I also found this confusing and sad when I discovered that `shared_ptr` is the **default** pointer type and not `unique_ptr` or something that doesn't make reasoning about lifetime and therefore invariance really hard.  You wouldn't make everything a `friend` class and throw out the ability to reason about private state, so why do we make everything a `shared_ptr` and throw out the ability to reason about lifetime?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-15**:
Tyler: I won't argue with you about the "`shared_ptr` should not be used like this" aspect. I fully agree.

But that's not what this was about.

Please don't conflate different issues.

Macros are a standard part of C and C++, and editors do have support for those.

I'm not dismissing the frustration reported by the OP, or yours. I just wanted to let (future) readers know that there is tooling which will make your life as a C++ programmer much easier. No need to "text search" for type definitions.

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2020-09-15**:
"Macros are a standard part of C and C++" (only because deprecating part of C is not something C++ has been willing to do yet).  If they'd get rid of macros and operator[] c++ would be a much better language imho.  This has really devolved, I would just like anyone who finds this to try to avoid using `Ptr` if they can help themselves.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-15**:
Could all be, but fact is that right now, it's part of the language (or at least supported by the toolchain).